# Python - Logging pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, pyautogui

So main problem is that i don't know how to log a click in python.
I've got something like this

```
import pyautogui as g
import logging
from datetime import datetime
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
LOG_FILENAME = datetime.now().strftime('C:/Log_Test/log_%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%Y.log')
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, format=LOG_FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG)
button = g.click(500, 400)
if button == True:
    logging.info('Good Click')
elif button == False:
    logging.error('Bad Click')
```

It create a file with good name and everything but it's empty.
I think that it's a problem with this "if" statement, but i don't know how to change it. Later i would want to change the x,y coordinates to locateOnScreen function, but still, i want to log it.

Comment: It seems `pyautogui.click` doesn't return a `bool`, `button` will always be `None`. It may raise an exception though which you can `try`/`except` though. What are the good click and bad click cases meant to represent?

Answer (score 0):

pyautogui.click doesn't return a boolean

I'd recommend just trying if there is any exception and use a try catch to log the error or if it succeded